# Cannot write superscripts and subscripts in ConTeXt

Tags: math-mode, fonts, context

Here is my mwe:

```
\setupbodyfont[gentium,12pt]
\mainlanguage [gr]

\starttext

 text in greek , $\alpha^{i}_{j}$

\stoptext
```

I compile my document using ConTeXt(LuaTeX) and I get the following error:

> Math error: parameter \Umathsup_shift_up\textstyle is not set

This problem appears (so far) when I try to use a subscript/superscript in my equations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gentium` is just a serif typeface. To use math, you need to define a math typeface as well. I am not sure which math font looks the best with Gentium; I am using Latin Modern just to show how to get rid of the error message.

```
\definetypeface [mainface] [rm] [serif] [gentium][default]
\definetypeface [mainface] [ss] [sans]  [modern] [default]
\definetypeface [mainface] [tt] [mono]  [modern] [default] 
\definetypeface [mainface] [mm] [math]  [modern] [default]

\setupbodyfont[mainface,12pt]
\mainlanguage [gr]

\starttext

text in greek, $\alpha^{i}_{j}$

\stoptext
```

Comment: I believe `TeX Gyre Pagella` fits better with `Gentium` font

Comment: To use pagella as the math font, replace the last line with `\definetypeface [mainface] [mm] [math]  [pagella] [default]`